# Load OSGi class from JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, osgi, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am calling some C++ code that tries to load a Java class, e.g.

```
JNIEnv *jenv = ...
jclass cls = jenv->FindClass("org/some/bundle/SomeClass");
```

Now, the problem is that this class resides in an OSGi bundle, and the code above cannot find my class.

This problem only arise when running unit tests (Tycho-surefire headless tests). Is there a simple way to force the OSGi framework to find my class from JNI? On the Java side, I suspect something like `Dynamic-ImportPackage` could have fixed my problem. I am unwilling to change the third party C++ library just to get it working with the test framework, so I prefer a solution on the Java test setup / configuration side, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FindClass method of JNIEnv only searches the contents of the system ClassLoader as defined by the global application classpath. Since OSGi does not use the global classpath, it is no surprise that this doesn't work.

In general whenever loading a class, you need to specify not just the class name but also the classloader that should load it. This is an inevitable requirement of modularity. So your code needs to be able to find the bundle that you expect to contain the class, and then call its loadClass method. You can do this directly in C++ code, but it may be easier to write a Java utility method to do it and then just call that method from C++.

Comment: I understand, and it confirms my assumption. The question is, can I somehow work around this by a simple reconfiguration, without changing the C++ library (which I don't have direct control over)?

Comment: For example, I tried setting "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra" to the bundle of the class loaded by the C++ code, but it did not help.

Comment: Not really. As I said, JNIEnv reads the global application classpath. It's possible to make classpath classes visible into OSGi bundles by exporting them from the system bundle... this is what the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` setting achieves. But what you need is to go the other direction: importing from a OSGi Bundle into the system bundle, which is impossible. The only way I can think of is to move the class into the global classpath, and export it from there.

Comment: OK, thank you. What you write makes total sense. I am currently not able to do this (needs some thought and refactoring), but I believe that I could make this work using your suggestion. The pain of supporting legacy code in an Eclipse/RCP environment :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not 100% sure that your case is like mine.

In my RCP I used to get the exception:

> ClassNotFoundException: com.tool.packageA.IWantToLoadThisClass cannot be found by com.tool.packageB_1.0.0.qualifier

---

A simple solution was to:

- Add **com.tool.packageA** to **com.tool.packageB** *MANIFEST.MF* Require-Bundle.

I though wanted to avoid that solution, because I was able to load other classes found in other packages normally **com.tool.packageC, com.tool.packageD** (This wasn't done by me though so I didn't know how it worked).

---

Searching around I came to find the other solution which I ended up using to keep things similar to the current working packages (**com.tool.packageC, com.tool.packageD**).

The solution was:

- Using **Eclipse-BuddyPolicy** and **Eclipse-RegisterBuddy** [see here for detailed info](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements)

This is how to get it to work:

1. Add `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered` to **com.tool.packageB** *MANIFEST.MF*
2. Add `Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: com.tool.packageB` to **com.tool.packageA** *MANIFEST.MF*
3. Add `Require-Bundle: com.tool.packageB` to **com.tool.packageA** *MANIFEST.MF*

Now **com.tool.packageA.IWantToLoadThisClass** will be visible from **com.tool.packageB** and you will be able to find it when `jenv->FindClass("com/tool/packageA/IWantToLoadThisClass");`.

I hope this helps.